# Unable to deploy JSF with Managed Beans

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, jboss, managed-bean

I am very new to JSF and still trying to run the basic application to understand how the things work.

**I am using JBoss AS 7 and JSF 2.0(Mojarra 2.0.3-FCS)**

First I created a normal Application which was used to print on the page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputLabel value="Hello World"></h:outputLabel>
</h:body>
</html>
```

It works and I can understand pretty much everything.

During the Deployment, it did give two warnings

```
21:19:06,193 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.faces.vendor.Tomcat6InjectionProvider:org.apache.catalina.util.DefaultAnnotationProcessor' for service type 'com.sun.faces.spi.injectionprovider'
21:19:06,195 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.faces.vendor.Jetty6InjectionProvider:org.mortbay.jetty.plus.annotation.InjectionCollection' for service type 'com.sun.faces.spi.injectionprovider'
```

But any how it worked(However it would be nice, if it would go away)

---

**The part where it started giving Problem.**

Then, I tried using Managed Bean and it started creating problem

So I created a Bean

```
package org.demojsf.samples.beans;

import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean ( value= "greet")
@RequestScoped
public  class GreetBean {
    public GreetBean(){

    }
    public String greet() {
        return "Greeting"   ;   
    }

}
```

**Please note that I tried @ManagedBean(name="greet") but eclipse was treating it as an error and the fix that it provided was to change it to value. Hence value is there**

**The XHTML code is something like :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputLabel value="#{greet.greet()}"></h:outputLabel>
</h:body>
</html>
```

and then it threw this error

```
21:30:44,992 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.faces.vendor.Tomcat6InjectionProvider:org.apache.catalina.util.DefaultAnnotationProcessor' for service type 'com.sun.faces.spi.injectionprovider'
21:30:44,994 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.faces.vendor.Jetty6InjectionProvider:org.mortbay.jetty.plus.annotation.InjectionCollection' for service type 'com.sun.faces.spi.injectionprovider'
21:30:45,321 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-1) Initializing Mojarra 2.1.7-jbossorg-1 (20120227-1401) for context '/third'
21:30:45,374 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-5) Failed to define class org.demojsf.samples.beans.GreetBean in Module "deployment.first.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/demojsf/samples/beans/GreetBean : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:63) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:55) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]

21:30:45,449 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-2) Failed to define class org.demojsf.samples.beans.GreetBean in Module "deployment.first.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/demojsf/samples/beans/GreetBean : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:79) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]

21:30:45,471 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."first.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."first.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "first.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011030: Could not configure component greet
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:92)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.demojsf.samples.beans.GreetBean from [Module "deployment.first.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:79)
    ... 6 more

21:30:46,740 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-1) Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final
21:30:47,002 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /third
21:30:47,021 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "first.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"first.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"first.war\".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"first.war\""}}
21:30:47,026 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015871: Deploy of deployment "third.war" was rolled back with no failure message
21:30:47,054 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment first.war in 30ms
21:30:47,078 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment third.war in 50ms
21:30:47,080 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."first.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."first.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "first.war"

21:30:47,082 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014654: Composite operation was rolled back
21:30:47,084 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"first.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"first.war\".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"first.war\""}}}}
```

Comment: What JDK version are you using to 1) compile your code? 2) Eclipse uses to run and 3) to run JBoss AS 7? I think you need to apply all your applications I've highlighted (including your applicaton) to use J2SE 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are compiling your code with Java 8, but the application server is running with Java 6/7 (depending on your environment).

In eclipse, see [Changing the Java compiler version for a Java EE project](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftchangejavalevel.html).

[image: Project Facet Java version in eclipse]

---

Try this:

```java
package org.demojsf.samples.beans;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@RequestScoped  
@ManagedBean(name = "greet")
public  class GreetBean {

    public String greet() {
        return "Greeting"   ;   
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, the main problem is solved but still I am unable to see anything. The output is just blank. There is another issue of using value instead of name with @ManagedBean. Can you please help me that :) .... Thanks

Comment: Hi, @Ayushchoubey I updated my answer based on your comment. I hope it helps.

Comment: Ok, Worked like a charm. That was stupid of me. Wrong Package name. Thank you. Finally, It worked. I was stuck there for 2 days. Thanks :)